# Upgrading golang through modules

Tags: go, go-modules

I am upgrading my project dependencies through golang modules. Ran

```golang
mod init
```

command and got this issue, not sure how to resolve.

```
$ go mod init 
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko
go: copying requirements from Gopkg.lock
go: converting Gopkg.lock: stat github.com/google/go-github@v18.2.0: github.com/google/go-github@v18.2.0: invalid version: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v18
```

Invalid version: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v18

Updates:

```
removed Gopkg.toml
go mod init
go build
fixed some dependencies related to HighwayHash
finally stuck on below error
```

```
go: github.com/moby/buildkit@v0.6.3 requires
        github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.3.0-0.20190507210959-7c1e88399ec0: invalid pseudo-version: version before v1.3.0 would have negative patch number
```

Comment: Have you tried this without Gopkg.lock?

Comment: you mean I should delete goplkg.lock and then try go mod init?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would try. Looks like that module is at v28 already.

Comment: What does 'go get -u' say?

Comment: go get .: path /home/prary3/go_projects/src/github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko is not a package in module rooted at /home/prary3/go_projects/src/github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko

Comment: @BurakSerdar that helped but faced new issue after running go mod tidy 
go: github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/pkg/util imports
        github.com/minio/HighwayHash: github.com/minio/HighwayHash@v1.0.0: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/minio/highwayhash
                but was required as: github.com/minio/HighwayHash

Comment: It looks like a capitalization problem. You might need to change your include path to highwayhash, but I've never seen this myself so I  may be wrong.

Comment: updated the fresh errors

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's a problem with the `containerd` commit you are using. You can replace that with a working `containerd` version or commit.

You can achieve this by adding the following section to your `go.mod` file.

```golang
replace (
    github.com/containerd/containerd v1.3.0-0.20190507210959-7c1e88399ec0 => github.com/containerd/containerd v1.3.0
)
```

If you want to have the recent changes in your project, you can use the following instead of the previous section.

```golang
replace (
    github.com/containerd/containerd v1.3.0-0.20190507210959-7c1e88399ec0 => github.com/containerd/containerd v1.3.1-0.20191118201915-499f346be357
)
```

Reference : https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3031#issuecomment-541737892

Comment: Except containerd is a depenedency of `moby/buildkit`, and not the project from the asker. Try to update everything using `go get -u`.

Answer (score 0):

Update Nov. 2020, from [issue 3031](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3031#issuecomment-690619939) and [`containerd/cri` PR1377](https://github.com/containerd/cri/pull/1377#issuecomment-705172957)

`go mod init` should now work. The move to go modules has been completed for [`github.com/containerd/containerd`](https://github.com/containerd/containerd).

The go.mod looks complete:

module github.com/containerd/containerd

```
go 1.15

require (
        github.com/BurntSushi/toml v0.3.1
        github.com/Microsoft/go-winio v0.4.15-0.20200908182639-5b44b70ab3ab
        github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim v0.8.10
        ...
```

Update Jan. 2021: [`containerd/containerd` issue 3031](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3031#issuecomment-766701615) just got completed with [PR 4760](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/pull/4760) "Move to Go modules".

[Commit fbf1a72](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/commit/fbf1a72de7da110187b7d3dace433914b9beca10) from last Dec. 2020 has all the details, with a [brand new `go.mod`](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/fbf1a72de7da110187b7d3dace433914b9beca10/go.mod).